# Graph API: how to filter contacts email addresses by a domain and remove odata.etag

Tags: json, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

Currently Microsoft Graph API is fetching only limited number of contacts

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$select=emailAddresses
```

I'm trying to fetch specific domain users from contacts like `gmail.com`,`yahoo.com`,`hotmail.com` etc.

How can I filter contacts by a domain?

Is it possible to remove the `@odata.etag` from the response?

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"EQAAABYAAAA7dvnHzGk5R7sHHysSXK7DAACr9QQo\"",
    "id": "AQMkADAwATMwMAItMzdhMS02YTgwLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA1uMJPrjGhBAoUs_D2djgpAHADt2_cfMaTlHuwcfKxJcrsMAAAIBDgAAADt2_cfMaTlHuwcfKxJcrsMAAACr-pPFAAAA",
    "emailAddresses": [
        {
            "name": "bmalet@yahoo.com",
            "address": "bmalet@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot filter contacts by a domain. You cannot apply any other operator or function with `$filter`, such as `ne`, `le`, and `startswith()`.

To remove `@odata.etag` you need to add a request header

```
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
```

Resources:

[Contacts: Optional query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)

Comment: thanks for answering , just for idea, can expand command be helpful if we apply along with the main query?

Comment: @DeepnilVasava Expand command can be used for contact's relationships (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contact?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) i.e. GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$select=emailAddresses,extensions&$expand=extensions